# ListView set height to show all items without scrolling

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app I have a `ListView` and I want to make the height big enough so that it shows all the items without having to scroll. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `ListView` is to make sure that you can display all the data on any screen size, by using scrolling on a smaller screens that cannot fit all the data.

I am sorry but your question does not make sense.
 You cannot set a fixed / static height value that will work across different devices. Setting fixed UI size does not make sense on `Xamarin.Forms` in general unless you will distribute your application for a single device with a fixed screen size.

Comment: You're right, if I really need a fixed size, then I should just use a grid.

Comment: Yes, might be that another kind of UI control will suit your needs better.